# How to get Request object in CustomPhaseListener?

Tags: servlets, cookies, request, jsf-1.2

Am hitting my `Servlet` from a link. Some `Cookies` would have been already set in Client. When my `Servlet` is hit, I want to retrieve these `Cookies`.

For eg., am hitting the link like http:/myDomain/myServlet/ServletReceiver

In `web.xml`, I have below code

```
<servlet>
   <display-name>ServletReceiver</display-name>
   <servlet-name>ServletReceiver</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>(location of my ServletReceiver)</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ServletReceiver</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/ServletReceiver</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

And my ServletReceiver code is below

```
public class ServletReceiver extends HttpServlet{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    // Do some checks here based on cookies obtained and redirect to corresponding page
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/index.jsf");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
 }
 }
```

My requirement is, when I retrieve some data from `Cookies`, I want to set it into bean. And since am creating an instance of the bean in `CustomPhaselistener` (and not in `ServletReceiver`), if I get the `request` object through which I can get cookie values then I can set that in my bean in PhaseListener.

My bean is `request` scoped.

So, is there a way to get `request` object in `CustomPhaseListener`?

Also, am retrieving Cookies in `doGet`method. Is that suggested?

Am using JSF 1.2

Comment: why dont you do it with session?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Sorry. I didn't get you exactly. You meant to say make my bean Session scoped ? Or, you meant to say share my values in Session attributes and retrieve that in PhaseListener? I don't want to make bean as Session scoped because its a simple page which takes input from Users and I want input fields not to be pre populated with earlier values when users makes a new request.

Comment: Share values through session attributes

Comment: @MaVRoSCy Am not sure doing so would be the correct way in my `Controller` (in my `doGet` method). So, am looking for a way in my PhaseListener. Please suggest